# Etymology: 'pray in aid'

Tags: etymology, ambiguity

> [P2. to pray in aid](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149429?rskey=GEO8Yk&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid28757220):  (a) {intr.} to call on the assistance of (also †for), to make use of, esp. in proving an argument (now rare);
>   (b) {trans.} (esp. Law) to ask for the assistance of (a person or thing) in pleading a case;
>   to use (a fact, law, etc.) in one's defence (cf. aid n. 5).
>   *[I omit the sentence on 'recent use', which doesn't interest me.]*

I also read [1913 Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+pray+in+aid), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pray_in_aid). and [P1. to pray (also call, crave) in aid](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.torontopubliclibrary.ca/view/Entry/4302?rskey=GEO8Yk&result=1#eid1140953067). 
Please help me dig deeper than the definitions above, which I already understand and so ask NOT about.
How should '**pray in aid**' be parsed?
To wit, how did these 3 bolded words combine to mean the definitions above?

I tried to guess,  but then was confused by the ambiguity. Does **pray in aid** mean:

1. You **pray in** [the language of] **aid** (e.g. in obsequious, trite diction)?

2. You **pray** for **aid** to dawn or emerge **in** your troubled life, as if by miracle?

I encountered this verb phrase in the Wikipedia article [*Hard cases make bad law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_cases_make_bad_law).

> Equity was introduced to mitigate the rigour of the law. But in the present case **it has been prayed in aid** to do injustice on a large scale - to defeat the intentions of a dead man - to deprive his children of the benefits he provided for them - and to expose his estate to the payment of tax of over £600,000. I am glad to find that we can overcome this most unjust result.

Comment: *Pray in aid* is a legal term, which has a specific legal meaning, and has been used since the 16thcentury. I am not convinced from your question that you do understand the meaning. There is a significant entry in the OED, so if you so wish I will post it as an answer. However I am not inclined to do so whilst your question is about etymology, which is not given in the OED. .

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for your honesty; yes, I admit that I might've failed to understand the meaning. So please advise. However, I did read the OED which is mum on the etymology; so please don't simply replicate that as an answer (but please feel free to quote it).

Comment: @WS2 Thank you for your answer. Could I please check if you explained the etymology? I forgot to declare that I already tried the OED and did read the definitions; so I just edited my OP above.

Answer (score 3):

***Pray in aid*** exists as both a noun and a verb, and has in each respect, a specifically legal meaning. The following is extracted from the Oxford English Dictionary (OED).

> Noun. *Pray in aid* Law. Help in defending an action, legally claimed
>   from someone who has a joint interest in the defence. Freq. to have
>   aid of    . Cf. to pray (also call, crave) in aid at Phrases 1. Now
>   rare (hist. in later use).
>
> Verb. *Pray in Aid* P2.  to pray in aid :  (a) intr. to call on the
>   assistance of (also †for), to make use of, esp. in proving an argument
>   (now rare);  (b) trans. (esp. Law) to ask for the assistance of (a
>   person or thing) in pleading a case; to use (a fact, law, etc.) in
>   one's defence (cf. aid n. 5). In recent use, when an of-phrase
>   follows, the latter usually denotes the thing which it is desired to
>   assist or defend.
>
> 1999   Internat. & Compar. Law Q. 48 847   A State may not pray in aid
>   deficiencies in its internal legal order to escape its international
>   obligations.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the phrase "pray in aid" is that the verb *pray* has the sense of "request" or "seek" and the prepositional phrase *in aid* has the sense "in support of [one's cause]" or "by way of assistance to [one's cause]."

Unlike the OED entry cited in WS2's interesting answer, *Black's Law Dictionary*, fourth edition (1968), does not categorize "pray in aid" as a noun for some purposes and a verb for others. Instead it offers a single entry (with examples):

> PRAY IN AID. In old English practice. To call upon for assistance. In real actions, the tenant might *pray in aid* or call for assistance of another, to help him to plead, because of the feebleness or imbecility of his own estate. 3 Bl[ackstone's] Comm[entaries] 300.